# Creating custom table views in xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

Creating custom table view in XIB doesnt load the custom cells. Please anyone can provide me with the sample it would be great help.

Comment: have you tried something like this? [self.tableView registerNib:@"MyTableViewCell" forCellReuseIdentifier:@"my_cell"];

Answer (score 0):

Create a UITableViewCell subclass with xib file and then load the Cell to your tableView,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];   
    UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourTableViewCellName" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

And then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourTableViewCellName *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];  
return cell;
```

}

hopefully this will help you.